# How create a single CodeNarc report for a multiple-project Gradle build

Tags: gradle, codenarc

I have a Gradle multi-projects build where each subproject creates its own CodeNarc report.

Is it possibile to create a single CodeNarc analysis report for all the projects in my build instead of a separate report for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own CodeNarc task and configure it with the sourcesets of all its subprojects as follows.

```
task supernarc(type: CodeNarc) {
  def allGroovySourceDirs = subprojects.collect { Project p -> p.sourceSets.main.allGroovy.getSrcDirs() }.flatten()

  allGroovySourceDirs.each {
    source(it)
  }

  // BTW, if you know you have some violations and don't want the builds to fail because of too many violations, you can increase the threshold as follows
  maxPriority1Violations = 5
  maxPriority2Violations = 5
  maxPriority3Violations = 5
```

}

I created this [sample on Github](https://github.com/neversleepz/CodeNarcSubprojectsAsOneReport) for you so you could see a project using it.

Does that help?

Cheers
Kon

Comment: It looks cool, but unfortunately I'm getting this error message `Could not find property 'allGroovy' on source set 'main'`. Could it be a problem with Gradle version? I'm using Gradle 2.1

Comment: I'm using 2.1 also.  Are you applying the codenarc plugin to the root project and the subprojects?

Answer (score 0):

For me something like this is possible to aggregate several source-sets to one report, while Im using version 3.3.0:

```
codenarc {
    toolVersion = codenarcVersion
    ignoreFailures = true
    configFile = rootProject.file('config/codenarc/codenarc.groovy')
    sourceSets = [
        sourceSets.main,
        sourceSets.test,
        sourceSets.integrationTest,
        sourceSets.systemTest,
        sourceSets.acceptanceTest,
    ]
    reportFormat = 'html' // 'console'
    maxPriority1Violations = 0
    maxPriority2Violations = 1
    maxPriority3Violations = 300
}
```